# Change Deployment descriptor web.xml on glassfish 3

Tags: java, glassfish-3, web.xml

Is there anyway to change certain web.xml parameters of an already deployed application in the glassfish?

Comment: Why don't you redeploy with the changed parameters ?

Comment: I want this to be done in a place where source is not available to repackage it after changing. And also i do not want to tamper the web.xml packaged in the war file. So I want that to be changed while it is deployed or during redeployment time.

Comment: The person whoever down voted this, can you please explain it through a comment. A down vote without a comment is absolutely useless.

Comment: What are the things you want to change?

Answer (score 1):

If you change directly in the file-system, no one will understand later, why and when the changes have been done. So this is bad!

But it's easy: Just change the web.xml of the deployed application and restart the glassfish domain. You will find the web.xml somewhere near

/PATH/TO/glassfish3/glassfish/domains/DOMAIN/applications/APP-NAME/WAR-NAME/WEB-INF/web.xml

if deployed in a standalone instance. Otherwise it is somewhere below the ..../nodes folder.

Edit: In a cluster environment, a sync from the deployment manager will override your changes.

Comment: Yes, that makes sense. Actually what I was looking for is to edit this through glassfish itself, rather than I going to the file system and doing the edit.

Comment: I do not agree with the statement that modifying the web.xml is an ugly hack. IBM WebSphere Application Server allows you to review and modify all the settings in all deployment descriptors of an ear file both at deployment time and after. I agree your application should works out-of-the-box without any further configuration but there are situations where you need some tweaking. There is nothing bad about it unless not properly documented.

Comment: Does this work for glassfish-ejb-jar.xml / sun-ejb-jar.xml ejb deployment descriptor as well. I am using Glassfish v2, and when I change the sun-ejb-jar.xml file in the file-system and restart the domain I don't see the changes being applied.